# Extension of Lipschitz map

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Suppose (M,d) is a metric space and $N\subset M$ is finite, $\varepsilon >0$. Also let there exist $u, v \in M$ and $u\neq v$ such that
$$ (1-\varepsilon)(d(x,y)+d(u,v)) \leqslant d(x, u) +d(y, v) $$
$\forall x, y \in N$

Now if we consider an $1+\varepsilon$ -Lipschitz map $f:N\bigcup \{u, v\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then does it always admit an $1+\varepsilon$ -Lipschitz extension to the whole space M?

Comment: As long as you consider real-valued fuctions, each Lipschitz function on any subset of any metric space has a Lipschitz extension preserving the Lipschitz constant, see Thm 1 here: https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=bams%2F1183497871

Comment: @Gerd Thanks a lot.....